# Converting a website to flash SWF

Tags: flash, web

I'd like to know if there's any way by which I could convert a set of connected web pages to a  flash file (SWF)

In effect the website ( a set of connected webpages) should be replicated onto flash - the flash file functioning as an interactive document exactly like the website.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There are several online file converters, Just search flash to HTML conversion.
hhttp://www.office-converter.com/Convert-to-Flash is one.

I personally have never don this, since I would just rebuild it myself.

Can I ask why you want to do this?  Could you possibly just use the HTML itself?  Remember flash doesn't work on several device.

Comment: the set of HTML file(s) is being generated programatically . Hence the need to convert them

Answer (score 0):

Take a video capture and embed it in a FLA timeline, then edit the functionality on a layer over it, in sync to the frames.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion , however I was looking to do this programatically and not manually